# "Cannot find module" during Jest tests, renders app fine - package published on github

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, jestjs, create-react-app

I appreciate there are a lot of "cannot find module" questions on S.O., but I have been through a LOT of them and not found an answer, so perhaps this case is different. I have a private package - a library of components - that we created using Create React App and published using github packages. It contains Jest unit tests that work fine, and the components are rendered fine by our website which uses the library. We now want to add Jest tests to the website (a Next app), but we are getting the following error:

```
Cannot find module '@organisation/package-name' from 'pages/index.js'
```

Our library is bundled using Rollup. The library's package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "@organisation/package-name",
  "repository": "https://github.com/organisation/package-name.git",
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
  },
  "version": "2.3.0",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "type": "module",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.21.0",
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^15.16.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "12.1.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.14",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.17.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.5",
    "cookies-next": "^2.1.1",
    "mime": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "^12.3.1",
    "node": "^18.0.0",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "patch-package": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.10.0",
    "react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.30.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-twitter-embed": "^4.0.4",
    "swiper": "^9.2.4",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "uninstall": "^0.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!swiper|ssr-window|dom7)/\" --env=jsdom",
    "coverage": "npm run test -- --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "format": "prettier --check --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "format:fix": "prettier --write --ignore-path .gitignore ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.3",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^24.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-image": "^3.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^6.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "@semantic-release/changelog": "^6.0.3",
    "@semantic-release/git": "^10.0.1",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "rollup": "^2.79.1",
    "rollup-plugin-delete": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^4.2.3",
    "rollup-plugin-node-externals": "^5.1.2",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-polyfill-node": "^0.12.0",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.34.1",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

Rollup config:

```
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import externals from 'rollup-plugin-node-externals';
import del from 'rollup-plugin-delete';
import pkg from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

export default [
  {
    input: './src/index.js',
    plugins: [
      del({ targets: 'dist/*' }),
      externals({ deps: true }),
      nodeResolve({
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      }),
      babel({
        babelHelpers: 'runtime',
        exclude: '**/node_modules/**',
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      }),
      commonjs(),
      postcss(),
    ],
    output: [{ file: pkg.module, format: 'es' }],
  },
];
```

In the website, the package.json is:

```
{
  "cacheDirectories": [
    ".next/cache"
  ],
  "name": "our-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "serve out",
    "prod": "next build && next start",
    "preexport": "npm run build",
    "export": "next export",
    "prestart": "npm run export",
    "format": "prettier --check --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "format:fix": "prettier --write --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "test": "jest",
    "e2e": "npx playwright test",
    "e2e:codegen": "npx playwright codegen"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@contentful/app-sdk": "^4.4.0",
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^15.11.1",
    "@react-aria/ssr": "^3.3.0",
    "algolia": "^0.0.0",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.13.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.8.1",
    "contentful": "^9.1.6",
    "contentful-export": "^7.19.34",
    "contentful-management": "^9.0.0",
    "cookies-next": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "^12.3.1-canary.0",
    "node": "^16.13.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.2",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^1.10.0",
    "react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.30.2",
    "react-twitter-embed": "^4.0.4",
    "swiper": "^9.0.5",
    "xmlbuilder": "^15.1.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^16.13.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.31.0",
    "@organisation/package-name": "2.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
    "csv-parse": "^5.3.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "jest": "^29.4.3",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

We access the library from the index.js page like this:

```
import {
  Loader,
  SeoAndMeta,
  Layout,
  ExitPreview,
  DynamicComponent,
} from '@organisation/package-name';
```

... using path aliasing, which works fine for rendering. The tests are currently basically empty, they are just attempting to render the page:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import HomePage from '../../pages/index';
import { mockProps } from './fixtures/fixtures';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

describe('Component: HomePage', () => {
  it('SHOULD render with the layout and the correct number of page sections', async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<HomePage {...mockProps} />);
  });
});
```

I have tried adding a CJS output to the rollup config, but this generates a new error stating that we are breaking the rules of hooks.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.